# Hbase quickly count number of rows

Tags: hadoop, hbase, bigdata

Right now I implement row count over `ResultScanner` like this

```
for (Result rs = scanner.next(); rs != null; rs = scanner.next()) {
    number++;
}
```

If data reaching millions time computing is large.I want to compute in real time that i don't want to use Mapreduce

How to quickly count number of rows.

Answer (score 110):

**Use RowCounter in HBase**
RowCounter is a mapreduce job to count all the rows of a table. This is a good utility to use as a sanity check to ensure that HBase can read all the blocks of a table if there are any concerns of metadata inconsistency. It will run the mapreduce all in a single process but it will run faster if you have a MapReduce cluster in place for it to exploit.

```
$ hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.RowCounter <tablename>

Usage: RowCounter [options] 
    <tablename> [          
        --starttime=[start] 
        --endtime=[end] 
        [--range=[startKey],[endKey]] 
        [<column1> <column2>...]
    ]
```

Comment: K, ran this, where does it print the answer? `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.RowCounter$RowCounterMapper$Counters ROWS=55438` <- that it?

Comment: HBase count 'table name' is super slow. Hive and Pig are faster. But this answer is the best in terms of speed!

Answer (score 38):

You can use the count method  in hbase to count the number of rows. But yes, counting rows of a large table can be slow.count 'tablename' [interval]

Return value is the number of rows.

This operation may take a LONG time (Run ‘$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar
hbase.jar rowcount’ to run a counting mapreduce job). Current count is shown
every 1000 rows by default. Count interval may be optionally specified. Scan
caching is enabled on count scans by default. Default cache size is 10 rows.
If your rows are small in size, you may want to increase this
parameter.

Examples:

```
hbase> count 't1'

hbase> count 't1', INTERVAL => 100000

hbase> count 't1', CACHE => 1000

hbase> count 't1', INTERVAL => 10, CACHE => 1000
```

The same commands also can be run on a table reference. Suppose you had a reference to table 't1', the corresponding commands would be:

```
hbase> t.count

hbase> t.count INTERVAL => 100000

hbase> t.count CACHE => 1000

hbase> t.count INTERVAL => 10, CACHE => 1000
```

Comment: This counter runs very slow and can be accessed from hbase shell only. For large tables its not recommended to use.

Comment: @articuno exactly

Answer (score 13):

If you cannot use `RowCounter` for whatever reason, then a combination of these two filters should be an optimal way to get a count:

```
FirstKeyOnlyFilter() AND KeyOnlyFilter()
```

The `FirstKeyOnlyFilter` will result in the scanner only returning the first column qualifier it finds, as opposed to the scanner returning all of the column qualifiers in the table, which will minimize the network bandwith. What about simply picking one column qualifier to return? This would work if you could guarentee that column qualifier exists for every row, but if that is not true then you would get an inaccurate count.

The `KeyOnlyFilter` will result in the scanner only returning the column family, and will not return any value for the column qualifier. This further reduces the network bandwidth, which in the general case wouldn't account for much of a reduction, but there can be an edge case where the first column picked by the previous filter just happens to be an extremely large value.

I tried playing around with `scan.setCaching` but the results were all over the place. Perhaps it could help.

I had 16 million rows in between a start and stop that I did the following pseudo-empirical testing:

```
With FirstKeyOnlyFilter and KeyOnlyFilter activated:

    With caching not set (i.e., the default value), it took 188 seconds.
    With caching set to 1, it took 188 seconds
    With caching set to 10, it took 200 seconds
    With caching set to 100, it took 187 seconds
    With caching set to 1000, it took 183 seconds.
    With caching set to 10000, it took 199 seconds.
    With caching set to 100000, it took 199 seconds.

With FirstKeyOnlyFilter and KeyOnlyFilter disabled:

    With caching not set, (i.e., the default value), it took 309 seconds
```

I didn't bother to do proper testing on this, but it seems clear that the `FirstKeyOnlyFilter` and `KeyOnlyFilter` are good.

Moreover, the cells in this particular table are very small - so I think the filters would have been even better on a different table.

---

Here is a Java code sample:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ResultScanner;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;

import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.RowFilter;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.KeyOnlyFilter; 
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.FirstKeyOnlyFilter; 
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.FilterList;

import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.CompareFilter.CompareOp;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.RegexStringComparator; 

public class HBaseCount {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();

        HTable table = new HTable(config, "my_table");

        Scan scan = new Scan(
            Bytes.toBytes("foo"), Bytes.toBytes("foo~")
        );

        if (args.length == 1) {
            scan.setCaching(Integer.valueOf(args[0]));
        }
        System.out.println("scan's caching is " + scan.getCaching());

        FilterList allFilters = new FilterList();
        allFilters.addFilter(new FirstKeyOnlyFilter());
        allFilters.addFilter(new KeyOnlyFilter());

        scan.setFilter(allFilters);

        ResultScanner scanner = table.getScanner(scan);

        int count = 0;

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        try {
            for (Result rr = scanner.next(); rr != null; rr = scanner.next()) {
                count += 1;
                if (count % 100000 == 0) System.out.println(count);
            }
        } finally {
            scanner.close();
        }

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        long elapsedTime = end - start;

        System.out.println("Elapsed time was " + (elapsedTime/1000F));

    }
}
```

---

Here is a [pychbase](https://github.com/mkmoisen/pychbase) code sample:

```
    from pychbase import Connection
    c = Connection()
    t = c.table('my_table')
    # Under the hood this applies the FirstKeyOnlyFilter and KeyOnlyFilter
    # similar to the happybase example below
    print t.count(row_prefix="foo")
```

---

Here is a Happybase code sample:

```
    from happybase import Connection
    c = Connection(...)
    t = c.table('my_table')
    count = 0
    for _ in t.scan(filter='FirstKeyOnlyFilter() AND KeyOnlyFilter()'):
        count += 1

    print count
```

---

Thanks to [@Tuckr and @KennyCason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11531273/1391717) for the tip.

Answer (score 9):

Use the [HBase rowcount map/reduce job](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/RowCounter.html) that's included with HBase

Comment: I used the source code for the rowcount example, and to save the result in a variable, i got the counter using:  `job.getCounters().findCounter(RowCounter.RowCounterMapper.Counters.ROWS).getValue();`

Answer (score 5):

Simple, Effective and Efficient way to count row in HBASE:

1. Whenever you insert a row trigger this API which will increment that particular cell.

   ```
   Htable.incrementColumnValue(Bytes.toBytes("count"), Bytes.toBytes("details"), Bytes.toBytes("count"), 1);
   ```
2. To check number of rows present in that table. Just use "Get" or "scan" API for that particular Row 'count'.

By using this Method you can get the row count in less than a millisecond.

Comment: this is a good way.But time hbase use increment is larger time that hbase put data.

Comment: what if the row already exists and its updated? this can count extra rows, right?

Comment: no.I want to tell 'time hbase use increment is larger time'. I want to run faster

Comment: And what if the loading data is not through the hbase API, like bulkload

Answer (score 5):

To count the Hbase table record count on a proper YARN cluster you have to set the map reduce job queue name as well:

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.RowCounter -Dmapreduce.job.queuename= < Your Q Name which you have SUBMIT access>
 < TABLE_NAME>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use coprocessor what is available since HBase 0.92. See [Coprocessor](http://hbase.apache.org/devapidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/coprocessor/package-summary.html) and [AggregateProtocol](https://hbase.apache.org/0.94/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/coprocessor/AggregateProtocol.html) and [example](http://www.thecloudavenue.com/2012/02/getting-started-with-hbase_20.html)

Comment: It worked for me, just a simple command "count 'myTable'", thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

**Two ways Worked for me to get count of rows from hbase table with Speed**

**Scenario #1**

If hbase table size is small then login to hbase shell with valid user and execute

```
>count '<tablename>'
```

Example

```
>count 'employee'

6 row(s) in 0.1110 seconds
```

**Scenario #2**

If hbase table size is large,then execute inbuilt RowCounter map reduce job:
Login to hadoop machine with valid user and execute:

```
/$HBASE_HOME/bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.RowCounter '<tablename>'
```

Example:

```
 /$HBASE_HOME/bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.RowCounter 'employee'

     ....
     ....
     ....
     Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=22594633728
                Total committed heap usage (bytes)=5093457920
        org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.RowCounter$RowCounterMapper$Counters
                ROWS=6
        File Input Format Counters
                Bytes Read=0
        File Output Format Counters
                Bytes Written=0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a scanner, in your scanner try to have it return the least number of qualifiers as possible.  In fact, the qualifier(s) that you do return should be the smallest (in byte-size) as you have available.  This will speed up your scan tremendously.

Unfortuneately this will only scale so far (millions-billions?).  To take it further, you can do this in real time but you will first need to run a mapreduce job to count all rows.

Store the Mapreduce output in a cell in HBase.  Every time you add a row, increment the counter by 1.  Every time you delete a row, decrement the counter.

When you need to access the number of rows in real time, you read that field in HBase.

There is no fast way to count the rows otherwise in a way that scales.  You can only count so fast.

Comment: Actually instead of "returning the least amount of qualifiers as possible" you shoul use `FirstKeyOnlyFilter`. as a Scan filter

Comment: @KennyCason What exactly does the `FirstKeyOnlyFilter` do? From the [thrift docs](, I couldn't understand this explanation: `[FirstKeyOnlyFilter] returns only the first key-value from each row` -- Does this mean it just picks the first cell and returns that one?

Comment: @KennyCason Ok after testing it out, it would appear to pick the first cell and return only that one. Why would you suggest this over @Tucker's suggestion to return the smallest qualifier? For example, if the first key-value picked by `FirstKeyOnlyFilter` has a really large value, then this would slow the scan down. On the other hand, if you pick the qualifier that has the smallest value, but that qualifier doesn't appear in all of the rows you want to count, then you will get an inaccurate count.

Comment: @KennyCason Ok I found it: Use `FirstKeyOnlyFilter() AND KeyOnlyFilter()`. The `KeyOnlyFilter` will prevent the column value from being transmitted over the network.

Answer (score 1):

U can find sample example here:

```
/**
     * Used to get the number of rows of the table
     * @param tableName
     * @param familyNames
     * @return the number of rows
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public long countRows(String tableName, String... familyNames) throws IOException {
        long rowCount = 0;
        Configuration configuration = connection.getConfiguration();
        // Increase RPC timeout, in case of a slow computation
        configuration.setLong("hbase.rpc.timeout", 600000);
        // Default is 1, set to a higher value for faster scanner.next(..)
        configuration.setLong("hbase.client.scanner.caching", 1000);

        AggregationClient aggregationClient = new AggregationClient(configuration);
        try {
            Scan scan = new Scan();
            if (familyNames != null && familyNames.length > 0) {
                for (String familyName : familyNames) {
                    scan.addFamily(Bytes.toBytes(familyName));
                }
            }
            rowCount = aggregationClient.rowCount(TableName.valueOf(tableName), new LongColumnInterpreter(), scan);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw new IOException(e);
        }
        return rowCount;
    }
```

Comment: Is there a way to prove that `configuration.setLong("hbase.client.scanner.caching", 1000);` works? For example, if I set it, and later call `scanner.getCaching()`, it will return `-1`.

Comment: AggregationClient   was removed  from hbase 3.1.0.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Hbase home directory and run this command,

**./bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.RowCounter 'namespace:tablename'**

This will launch a mapreduce job and the output will show the number of records existing in  the hbase table.

Answer (score -1):

> You could try hbase api methods!

org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.coprocessor.AggregationClient

Comment: Could you please provide a little more context for your answer as well as some links to relevant documentation?

Comment: AggregationClient is  not available in hbase 3.1.0