# How to calculate number of rows in a region when HBase table is split across multiple regions

Tags: hbase

How i can count the number of records in a region using hbase shell? If there is one region i can scan the table and get the number of records but if table is split across multiple regions, can i use a command on hbase shell to get this information? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can list the rows in shell for a given key range (region) :

```
f_keyonly = org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.KeyOnlyFilter.new();
f_firstkey = org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.FirstKeyOnlyFilter.new();
flist = org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.FilterList.new([f_keyonly, f_firstkey]);
scan 'mytable', {STARTROW => 'myStart', ENDROW => 'myEnd', FILTER =>  flist }
```

where myStart and myEnd are the startKey/endKey boundaries of a region. (check `http://myhost:60030/rs-status`)

If you just want to have the total number of rows then run the [RowCounter](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/RowCounter.html) job:
E.g:

```
hadoop jar /path/to/hbase.jar rowcounter mytable --range=myStart,myEnd
```

The result will be stored in the **RowCounterMapper** counter.

On the other hand, if you need counting frequently, you may consider implementing a [coprocessor](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/databases/database-design/9781449314682/coprocessors/id3222403) which runs on the server side.

Further discussion can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11375098/hbase-quickly-count-number-of-rows) .