# Can't find the method when use Hbase RowCounter

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

My question is about could I/how to use mapreduce.RowCounter in standalone hbase.

I run a standalone hbase(1.3.1) in docker without hadoop.

In order to use rowCounter, I download and put the jar package  (org\apache\hbase\hbase-mapreduce\2.0.0\hbase-mapreduce-2.0.0.jar) under /hbase/lib ,then restart the docker.

When I run the script:org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.RowCounter ,it occurs：ArgumentError: Java package `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce' does not have a method`RowCounter'.

I guess it is beacause the path is wrong,or mapReduce is based on hdfs so it can not be run in a standalone hbase without hadoop.

But I am lack of knowledge to verify it.

Reference:
[Hbase quickly count number of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11375098/hbase-quickly-count-number-of-rows)

Comment: Sorry to bother,but I find the way to solve the problem.It went wrong because I start the hbase shell and ran the setence at first.It should be:run hbase org.apache.hbase.mapreduce.RowCounter 'tablename'  under hbase/bin
.

Answer (score 0):

Row counter is based on map reduce. so you need yarn to run it. it is not possible run it without hadoop. check your hadoop installation and be sure that yarn is started.