# How to use RowCounter in Apache HBase by Spring Boot API?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api, hbase

HBase table has Id column. I want to check it, if it isn't exist, controller calls add() method, if it's exist then controller calls `update()` method. Id value is injected from Controller class to Service class. How can I count row number or check if Id existed?

More, my model has `create_at` and `update_at`, how can I update and dont update create_at column? `create_at` is generated one time when add(), update_at store the last update time.

```java
record.setCreateAt(Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now()));
record.setUpdateAt(Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now()));
```

Comment: Where would you get the id value, if it does not exists in database?

Comment: @Popeye if Id does not exists in hbase, counter(): row_counter = 0 then add() is called, if row_counter = 1 then update() is called

Comment: I find that statement but it looks like not fit my purpose.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11375098/hbase-quickly-count-number-of-rows